# Enter Shell Of already Running gdb

Tags: shell, gdb

I have gdb running on cpp application process on remote machine, and  accidenttly close terminal. How do i get into this gdb shell again?

```
$ pidof application
12345
$ pidof gdb
23456
```

gdb was started like "gdb --pid=12345" which is attached to process.

How do I  get back into gdb shell from external shell. Is there any way like 
"enter-gdb-shell with pid 23456"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) does what you want: attach a terminal to a running process.

Comment: sudo reptyr 31146
[-]Process 31145 (sudo) shares 31146's process group. Unable to attach.
(This most commonly means that 31146 has suprocesses).
How to run reptyr for a process containing child processes